# Issue using dplyr to mutate values of specified groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I've got some values, which are labeled as being part of groups.

In some groups, the spread of the values is too great.

I want to make an adjustment to the lower values of those groups.

I can generate some synthetic data like so:

```
groups <- floor(runif(1000,1,100))
values <- rnorm(1000,0,1)
df     <- data.frame(group=groups,val=values)
```

Let's find the groups of interest:

```
groups_to_adjust <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(diff=max(val)-min(val)) %>% filter(diff>4) %>% select(group)
```

I *think* I can adjust them like so:

```
df <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(val=ifelse(group %in% groups_to_adjust, ifelse(val<0,val+4,val), val))
```

But NO! this does not work?

Using

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% filter(group %in% groups_to_adjust)
```

indicates that the `%in%` operator is, in fact, selecting no rows at all.

How can I perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to extract the "group" from the "groups_to_adjust" dataset.

```
r1 <- df  %>% 
        filter(group %in% groups_to_adjust$group)
```

as it is a 'data.frame' with two columns

```
str(groups_to_adjust)
#Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':       16 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ group: num  12 13 23 35 40 42 46 53 54 56 ...
# $ diff : num  4.09 4.66 4.52 4.3 4.33 ...
```

---

We can do this in a compact way with `filter`

```
df1 <- copy(df)
r2 <- df %>%
         group_by(group) %>%
         filter((max(val)- min(val)) > 4)
all.equal(r1, r2, check.attributes=FALSE)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Dang! Too easy. Thanks :-)

Comment: Is there a way to streamline this kind of operation?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how to apply this to the numeric mutation operation in the question.

Comment: @Richard I was picking up the one that didn't work for you.  For that code also, you don't need `rowwise()` and the `group %in% groups_to_adjust$group` can replace the one inside `ifelse`

Comment: Neither of them worked for me, the `filter` was just to indicate what failed.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to streamline a mutation of selected groups.

Comment: @Richard I showed the operations where it failed and also gave the output

Comment: I've split out the implied second question into a new question so that it is possible to accept your answer.

Comment: @Richard I am not sure why you are using `rowwise()` in the code

Comment: @Richard Did you meant to have an output like this `df %>% group_by(group) %>% filter((max(val)- min(val)) > 4) %>% left_join(df, ., by = "group") %>% mutate(val = ifelse(!is.na(val.y) & val.x < 0, val.x+4, val.x)) %>% select(-val.x,-val.y)`